# Trying to Calculate Last Month Values on Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I have a FinalRawData table with invoices for certain IDs (circuits) month to month. The values are stored in the column Total (USD). The dates are stored in the Invoice Date field or on another table as a Calendar[Date] value.

I need to calculate variance, so if it is more than 10% or $1000 compared to the previous month's invoice (not necessarily consecutive months), I need the variance value, either negative or positive. If not, I want it to be 0.

I have no idea why this formula is returning the current month's value instead of the difference against the previous one.

```
Amount_Difference =
    
    VAR CurrentRowDate = MAX('finalrawdata'[Invoice Date])
    
    VAR CurrentRowItem = MAX('finalrawdata'[Item])
    
    VAR CurrentRowAmount = MAX('finalrawdata'[Total (USD)])
    
    VAR PreviousMonthAmount =
    
    CALCULATE(
    
         SUM('finalrawdata'[Total (USD)]),
    
         'finalrawdata'[Invoice Date] = EOMONTH(CurrentRowDate, -1),
    
         'finalrawdata'[Item] = CurrentRowItem
    
    )
    
    VAR AmountDiff = CurrentRowAmount - PreviousMonthAmount
    
  RETURN

    IF(
    
      ABS(AmountDiff) > 1000 || ABS(AmountDiff) > CurrentRowAmount * 0.1,
    
      AmountDiff,
    
      BLANK()
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PreviousMonthAmount` isn't returning a value hence the result you are getting. A couple of obstacles:

- `PreviousMonthAmount` has row context and so it will only see itself - you will need one of the Filter functions to get the other rows.
- You mentioned that the months may not be consecutive - so `EOMONTH(CurrentRowDate, -1)` won't work here.

Try the following:

```
Amount_Difference = 
    
    VAR CurrentRowDate = [Invoice Date]
    
    VAR CurrentRowAmount = [Total (USD)]
    
    VAR PreviousMonthAmount =
    
    CALCULATE(
    
         MIN('finalrawdata'[Total (USD)]),
    
         TOPN(1,
           FILTER(
            ALLEXCEPT('finalrawdata', 'finalrawdata'[Item]), 
            'finalrawdata'[Invoice Date] < CurrentRowDate
           ), 
           [Invoice Date], DESC
         )    
    )
    
    VAR AmountDiff = IF(NOT ISBLANK(PreviousMonthAmount), CurrentRowAmount - PreviousMonthAmount)
    
  RETURN

    IF(
    
      ABS(AmountDiff) > 1000 || ABS(AmountDiff) > CurrentRowAmount * 0.1,
    
      AmountDiff,
    
      BLANK()
    )
```

The above gets the previous invoice value based on date.

`ALLEXCEPT('finalrawdata', 'finalrawdata'[Item])` gets all rows for the `Item`.

Comment: This makes all sense, but it's now saying a circular dependency was detected: FinalRawData[Amount_Difference]

Comment: Which other Calculated Columns are in that table? The Circular Dependency error should have a little more detail in it. Circular Dependency errors are common with multiple Calculated Columns on the same table. See if this helps: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/avoiding-circular-dependency-errors-in-dax/

Comment: Just one other calculated column

Circuit or Tax = IF([Payment Account] = "TAX", "TAX", [Circuit])

Don't think it has anything to do

Comment: I've updated the above - hopefully that will resolve it. (Removed `MAX` in the first two `VAR`,)

Comment: Still detecting a circular dependency. I suspect it's just the fact that we're comparing Invoice dates to invoice dates, same with Row Amounts?

Could EARLIER come in the mix?

Comment: Any other ideas Sam?

Comment: Can you share a sample PBIX?

Comment: I unfortunately can't as it is privileged data. For the CurrentRowDate and CurrentRowAmount variables, how can I specify them to be only the current row?

Maybe this could be fixed with a loop? No success so far... I've tried several suggestions by the article you shared earlier.